# How to start XAMPP MySQL by running a batch file?

Tags: mysql, batch-file, xampp

I have tried the following code in my batch file but it is not working

```
mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you maybe just forget to specify the absolute path. This works fine for me.

```
set root=c:\xampp\
%root%mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=%root%mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console
pause
```

if its not,what is the errormessage you get calling your file